# CSS Typerwriter animation gone wrong while working with width percentage

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So I took this piece of code: http://codepen.io/thiagoteles/pen/ogoxLw

And I tried to implement it in my blog's title: http://samanx.github.io/

For some reason I can't get it to stay in the center.

I tried creating an additional div and assigning to it this code:

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

But no solution: the problem is the:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.main-header {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 240px;
  height: 60%;
  padding: 15% 0;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 710px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.page-title {
  /* margin: 10px 0 10px 0; */
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
.page-description {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.01rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
/* Animation */

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) 0 infinite normal;
  -webkit-animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) 0 infinite normal;
  -moz-animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) 0 infinite normal;
  -o-animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) 0 infinite normal;
}
@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 24em;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 24em;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 24em;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 24em;
  }
}
@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header-content inner">
  <h1 class="page-title anim-typewriter">TaoJS - All things Javascript</h1>
  <h2 class="page-description">All things Javascript: resources, my problems, my solutions</h2>
</div>
```

My problem is that it moves too much to the right. If I remove the lines:

```
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 710px;
```

Then it's not working on mobile and smaller screens.

Comment: Have you tried setting `padding: 0px` to the page-title?

Comment: Yes, still not working, it's moving too much to the right and I can't understand why.

Comment: The problem is in the typewriter animation. Setting `width: 20em;` will align the text correctly. Maybe you should rethink this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is change some values according to your actual text changing the steps and width.

First some values to the `h1`:

```
.page-title {
  /*Add this styles to center and keep the fake cursor*/
  width:0;
  margin:auto;
  border-right:1px solid white;
}
```

Then change the animation to:

```
.anim-typewriter {
  -webkit-animation: typewriter 4s steps(29) 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(29) 0 infinite normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width:13em;
  }
}
```

Where `29` steps and `13em` width are values relative to the text you want to show.

#### Check this Snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.main-header {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 240px;
  height: 60%;
  padding: 15% 0;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 710px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.page-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  width:0;
  margin:auto;
  border-right:1px solid white;
}
.page-description {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.01rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
/* Animation */

.anim-typewriter {
  -webkit-animation: typewriter 4s steps(29) 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(29) 0 infinite normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width:13em;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header-content inner">
  <h1 class="page-title anim-typewriter">TaoJS - All things Javascript</h1>
  <h2 class="page-description">All things Javascript: resources, my problems, my solutions</h2>
</div>
```